# Inverse of Inner Product

Tags: inner-products

Given $v$ and the inner product $\langle u,v \rangle$ of two matrices, is there any way to calculate $u$ either directly or with some additional information?

I have found an example where someone computes $u$ given the vector cross product $(u \times v)$ using the following equation. Source: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=268477

$$ u = \frac{((u \cdot v)v - (u \times v) \times v)}{(v \cdot v)} $$

This assumes that you also have $(u \cdot v)$ and $(v \cdot v)$.

Is there some equivalent for the inner product? I can't seem to find anything specifically.

Comment: Consider a three dimensional space. If $u\cdot v=0$ and $u\ne0$, then $v$ is *any* vector in the plane orthogonal to $u$ passing through the origin. There's no way to recover $v$. Of course, some information is available on a two dimensional space, but the magnitude of $v$ is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Counterexample with $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $u = (0,1)$ and $v = (1,0)$ and $w = (-\pi,0)$. Note that $u \cdot v = 0 = u \cdot w$. So given $u \cdot x = 0$ and $u = (0,1)$, there is no way to distinguish between $x=v$ or $x=w$, for example...

Comment: Right. However lets say you have some additional piece of information like the magnitude the magnitude of x (which in this case still would not be enough). Is there any way to do it with some additional piece of information?

Comment: @user3905813 you should be able to put another constraint on $x$. Notice our constraint $u \cdot x = 0$ means that $x = (x_1,x_2)$ satisfies $x_2 = 0$, so another constraint, linearly independent of the first one would do the trick.